# dynamically align div jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I was trying to create a function that will make a box, align to the following options

1. `$("#roundbox").divAlign({vertical:"top",horizontal:"left"});` - should make the box on the top left of it's parent,
2. `$("#roundbox").divAlign({vertical:"top",horizontal:"center"});` - should make the box on the top center of it's parent,
3. `$("#roundbox").divAlign({vertical:"top",horizontal:"right"});` - should make the box on the top right of it's parent,
4. `$("#roundbox").divAlign({vertical:"center",horizontal:"left"});`
5. `$("#roundbox").divAlign({vertical:"center",horizontal:"center"});` -center of the screen
6. `$("#roundbox").divAlign({vertical:"center",horizontal:"right"});` - center but on the right side

can you please guide me on how to achieve with less code, unlike what I did below.

```
(function($){
     $.fn.extend({
          divalign: function (options) {
               var options =  $.extend({ // Default values
                    inside:window, // element, center into window
                    vertical:'center',
                    horizontal:'center'
               }, options);
               return this.each(function() {
                        var props = {position:'absolute'};
                        if (options.vertical=="center" && options.horizontal=="center"){
                            var div_height = $(options.inside).height() / 2;
                            var div_width = $(options.inside).width() / 2;
                            $.extend(props, {top:'50%'},{left: '50%'},{'margin-top': div_height + 'px'},{'margin-left': div_width+'px'});
                        }else if(options.vertical=="top" && options.horizontal=="left"){
                            $.extend(props, {'margin-top':'5%'},{left: '2%'});
                        }
                    $(this).css(props);
                    return $(this);
               });
          }
     }); })(jQuery);
```

visual representation:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Did you know jQuery UI has a function similar to this already? http://jqueryui.com/position/ might be worth looking at :)

Comment: would be nice if you will show demonstration.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand how to use jqueryui position, please help on how to achieve it, but would be nice if I could have it in my own function.
Thanks,

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5hLV/1/ :)